# Variables within wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

I have a left and right `wp_nav_menu` which displays on the front-end as one unordered list:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <?php
      // Left menu
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'left',
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => false,
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s' // Removes <ul> and wraps <li>
      ) );
      // Right menu
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'right',
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => false,
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s' // Removes <ul> and wraps <li>
      ) );
    ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As I'm repeating code here, I've created a variable called `$menu`, like so:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <?php
      // Left
      $menu = array('container' => false, 'menu_class' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s');
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'left',
        $menu
      ) );
      // Right
      wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'right',
        $menu
      ) );
    ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Is this the correct way of calling a variable within an array or is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_nav_menu()` is irrelevant here. An Array is an Array regardless. But no, this won't work. It will result in array that looks like this:

```
array(
    'theme_location'  => 'right',
    array(
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => false,
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s' // Removes <ul> and wraps <li>
    ),
)
```

To get the values in a single array you need to merge the arrays with `array_merge()`:

```
// Left
$menu = array('container' => false, 'menu_class' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s');
wp_nav_menu( array_merge( 
    array( 'theme_location'  => 'left' ),
    $menu
) );
// Right
wp_nav_menu( array_merge( 
    array( 'theme_location'  => 'right' ),
    $menu
) );
```